# getComputedStyle for the element when its parent is focused

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors, emotion, getcomputedstyle

I have a parent which sets a style for the children when it is focused. Which works perfectly when I compile my react project.

I am using react emotion, but it does not matter, because in the end I have usual css.

```
  const parentStyle = css`
    :focus {
      #child {
        border: 2px solid blue !important;
      }
    }
  `;
```

I want to get from within child element the border style.

I am using jest to test this and I tried something like this.

```
parent.simulate('focus');
const childNode = wrapper.find("#child");
const computedStyles = window.getComputedStyle(childNode);
expect(computedStyles.getPropertyValue('border')).toBe('2px solid blue');
```

So the expect is failing, it is not getting the border style.

Comment: What is your question? :)

Comment: @Webber sorry, just updated. my expect function is not working, its not getting style of the border

Comment: What is `childNode` set to?

Comment: updated again :)

Comment: Hmm, have you tried the longhand names? See first [note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle#Notes) in the documentation of computedStyles

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use .element instead (if you still need the answer):

`const computedStyles = window.getComputedStyle(childNode.element);`